# Find B-matrix for T([T]B) M2x2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

Define $T: M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$ to be the linear transformation defined by

$$T\left(     \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b\\
        c & d\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
        -2c & 2a+2b-2d\\
        -2c & 2c\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $B$ be the standard matrix for $M_{2x2}$
$$B = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0\\
      0 & 0
      \end{bmatrix},
     \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1\\
      0 & 0
      \end{bmatrix},
     \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 0\\
      1 & 0
      \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 0\\
      0 & 1
      \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Find the $B$-matrix for $T([T]_B)$

---

Not sure where to start with this one. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? It looks like you want to apply $T$ to $[T]_B$, but $[T]_B$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix...

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and show you how to find $[T]_B$, but it is unclear what you are looking for here.

$$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}_.$$

Therefore the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ is:

$$[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}_.$$